# Razor C# - Get data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix, I have created a database and put a table with a few rows of data. I can connect to it and get the data with the `WebGrid`, but it only provides a way to output the data using a table.

Here is my code for 'shows.cshtml':

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("TVPort");
    var shows_data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM shows");
    var shows_grid = new WebGrid(source: shows_data);
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is enumerate through each row returned by the query, and do whatever I want with the value of each column. But the `WebGrid` only allows you to output the data in a table. I just started using WebMatrix and the Razor syntax today.

Also (side-question here, didn't think it's enough to be its own question), is there any way to make a C# code file for my 'shows.cshtml' page? In Visual Web Developer 2010 each page has a 'page.aspx' file and a 'page.aspx.cs' where the 'page.aspx.cs' file lets you make custom functions to be used in the page, or perform a task when the page loads. Is there similar behavior using CSHTML in WebMatrix? Or is all of the code supposed to be inline with the actual page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer at [Working With Data : ASP.net](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data)

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM shows")) {
  <em>@row.title</em> - Cast: @row.cast
}
```

Comment: You are aware of the fact that what you're doing contradicts the whole idea of separation of concerns in MVC, are you?

Comment: @OferZelig Look, I am very new to ASP.net. I started using PHP and MySQL since I was 12 and I have not used another web development language until now, so I'm still getting the grasp of things. I don't even know what you mean by "separation of concerns". I'm an 18 year old guy just making a website for fun. Now, if you'd be willing to tell me what the idea of "separation of concerns" is, what I'm doing to contradict it, and what I should try to do to fix the contradiction.

Comment: @OferZelig I'm sorry if I don't see what is wrong with fetching data from a database in my webpage, so please enlighten me on how I should fetch my data and display it to the user.

Comment: @Bran Google it. :-) Your view should only display data, not retrieve it from the database. A place to do that is a controller, although that also isn't the best place.

Comment: How do I know if I'm using MVC? In VWD2010 it has MVC templates. But in WebMatrix my files are not 'page.aspx' and 'page.aspx.cs', where I'm assuming the .aspx is the view and the .aspx.cs is the controller. But the pages are only one .cshtml file.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I think there is some confusion. You may be right that there's no controller in WebMatrix, and the pages you link indeed show html, SQL and C# in one file. Dump that nonsense, it's the new DreamWeaver or FrontPage. Just download Visual Studio C# Express and take a look at full-blown ASP.NET MVC 4. This WebMatrix is teaching everything wrong.

Comment: @OferZelig Actually, I am not even using MVC. I am using WebMatrix WebPages where all code resides in a Razor template. I never mentioned MVC and the question is clearly tagged with 'WebMatrix' and 'Razor'.

Comment: @BrandonMiller so as CodeCaster suggests, if WebMatrix doesn't give you things like controllers (check if you have Controllers folder under the root of your web app) then it probably only allows you to mix logic & presentation in one .cshtml file which is bad.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ugh, the answer to another question I asked told me I should use WebMatrix. So I went 'Ask Question' -> 'Get Answer' -> 'Follow Answer' -> 'Ask Question About Answer' -> 'Get Told That Answer Is Wrong' -> 'Start Over'. It's like no matter who's answer I accept I am still always wrong. I spend time installing software from an answer just to get told I shouldn't use it.

Comment: @OferZelig Actually, I can put my logic in a C# file completely away from my CSHTML file. I've already tested it, I put my database logic in `Data.cs` and call it from `MyPage.cshtml`. In theory I could make a C# file (controller) for every CSHTML file (view).

Comment: @BrandonMiller that is not quite the way to go with MVC. Controllers are not exactly like code behind files from the WebForms world (.aspx.cs files). You often use one controller for multiple views (that's definitely not always true and not a rule, but just a common use case). And you don't call your logic from your `.cshtml`. You do all processing in the controller (or other places but let's stick with this for simplicity) and hand the view a pure object to show. The view should only access object's properties. Not `if`s and no data access.

Comment: @BrandonMiller My advice to you is to read some MVC tutorials to get the idea (check out _scottgu_'s tutorials. If you try doing something from the bottom up without understanding the flow, it will be hard and error prone...

Comment: MVC is great for large complex projects with multiple programers.  WebMatrix is great for lightweight smaller projects.  Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: ROFL at the peeps who think that Razor belongs to MVC - I got news for you - it was designed for ASP.NET Web Pages and borrowed by the MVC team as an additional view engine.

Answer (score 1):

You are going around this the wrong way! The MVC pattern has its strengths in separating the data-logic from the actual content and right now you are retrieving new data in the View (which doesn't leave much control to the Controller)!

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc for some great tutorials on how to use ASP.Net MVC and how to structure your classes and files (it will answer both your questions). It might seem a bit overdone if you used PHP and wrote every query directly in the same page before, but trust me, the code you create will be cleaner and a lot easier to maintain with ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: I am NOT using MVC. I am using WebMatrix WebPages. There is no concept of controllers. No where in my question did I say I was using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your side-question, I would say that using the Razor framework you cannot have a code-behind file. It mixes server-side code and client-side code together. If you want to have a code-behind file then you could use Asp.net Web Pages without the razor view engine on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For the side question i believe the @function{"insert code inside this block"} will allow you to create your custom functions inside your page. Hope this helps anyone else who may have similar question and end up here. Believe it or not there are some great documentation on how to get started @ http://www.asp.net/get-started. Just go through the tutorials.